# How to get 100% code coverage in server.js file of node js application

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

How to write unit test case for code which connects the server to the port 3000 in server.js file in Jest

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const routes = require("./routes/route.js");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './build')));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/", routes);

// Redirect to the React UI screen on default endpoint
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './build', 'index.html'));
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const server = app.listen(port, function () {
        let host = server.address().address;
        let port = server.address().port;
        console.log("Example app listening at : http://%s:%s", host, port);
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

I tried jest.spyOn and mocked the address using mockReturnBalue but it did not work. Below is the code

```
describe('Server', () => {
    it('should start the server when NODE_ENV is not "test"', () => {
    //   Mock the server.address() method to return a dummy address
      const mockAddress = {
        address: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000
      };
      jest.spyOn(app, 'server').mockReturnValue(mockAddress);
  
      // Start the server
      server = app.listen(3000);

      // Check if the server is listening
      expect(server.listening).toBe(true);
  
      // Check if the console.log method was called with the expected message
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        'Example app listening at : http://127.0.0.1:3000'
      );
    });
```

I get an error "Property `server` does not exist in the provided object"

Comment: (1) why do you feel you need 100% coverage on the file? (2) Why not test it using an integration test? Just let the server actually run and try sending a request to it

Comment: In our project we do only unit testing and the coverage has to be greater than 90%.
In this particular file, the coverage drops drastically if no unit test case is written for checking server connection. so looking how I can mock this and write a unit test for the same.

Comment: Well, in that case, my previous comment still stands. The only thing I'd maybe mock is `routes` - simply replace it with sth that returns one dummy route and then try requesting that route. It's up to you to decide if mocking it or leaving it unmocked (as a form of validation) will be beneficial for your process, though